# iOS Realm - CPU Overload and block UI when save data

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

i have one app that use Realm to save some data at the device. When i need to save a big list (9k object), my app is blocking the UI and the CPU got 130% for more than 10minutes. I tried to set save method to main thread but the UI still blocking. Anyone can help? I want the transaction don't block the UI and need to do in background.

This method i use to save my objects to realm db. It receive a list of participantes and i check before save if the object exists in my db.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for (Participante *p in participantes) {
        Participante *dbParticipante = [weakSelf fetchParticipanteById:p.identification];
        if(dbParticipante) {
            [dbParticipante setIdIngresso:p.idIngresso];
            [dbParticipante setIdentification:p.identification];
            [dbParticipante setIdCortesia:p.idCortesia];
            [dbParticipante setIdEvento:p.idEvento];
            [dbParticipante setNome:p.nome];
            [dbParticipante setDocumentoNumero:p.documentoNumero];
            [dbParticipante setCodigoIngresso:p.codigoIngresso];
            [dbParticipante setTipoIngresso:p.tipoIngresso];
            [dbParticipante save];
        } else {
            [p setSync:YES];
            [p save];
        }
    }
});
```

This method i use to save:

```
- (void)saveParticipante:(Participante *)participante {
[self writeTransactionWithWriteBlock:^(YSRealmWriteTransaction *transaction, RLMRealm *realm) {
    ParticipanteRealm *realmObject = [[ParticipanteRealm alloc] initWithMantleModel:participante];
    [realm addOrUpdateObject:realmObject];
}];
}

- (void)writeTransactionWithWriteBlock:(TransactionWriteBlock)writeBlock {
    RLMRealm *realm = [self realm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];

    if (writeBlock) writeBlock(self, realm);

    if (self.isCancelled) {
        [realm cancelWriteTransaction];
    } else {
        [realm commitWriteTransaction];
    }
}
```

I changed method save to persist all object in the same transaction but still is blocking UI. CPU has obtain small improvement: 90%

```
- (void)saveParticipante3:(NSMutableArray *)participanteList {
[self writeTransactionWithWriteBlock:^(YSRealmWriteTransaction *transaction, RLMRealm *realm) {
    for (Participante *p in participanteList) {
        ParticipanteRealm *realmObject = [[ParticipanteRealm alloc] initWithMantleModel:p];
        [realm addOrUpdateObject:realmObject];
    }
} completion:^(YSRealmStore *store, YSRealmWriteTransaction *transaction, RLMRealm *realm) {

}];
```

}

Comment: please show save method implementation.

Comment: Does the cpu load ever come back to normal ? If not, then somewhere there is an infinite loop running on ! Please post the relevant code that causes the overload on CPU!

Comment: There's two very important pieces of information that you're missing: 1) why is the main thread blocked if you're doing the write on a background thread? The backtrace from the main thread at the point it's blocked should reveal what's going on here. 2) What is the CPU time being spent doing during the write? An instruments time profile trace should reveal what's happening here.

Comment: One anti-pattern present in your code that jumps out at me is that you're performing write transactions within a loop, so each participant results in a separate write transaction being opened and then committed. You should instead perform all of the modifications within a _single_ write transaction. This won't necessarily address the specific problem you're seeing, but it will significantly speed up the modifications you're performing since it reduces the per-commit overhead to a single instance rather than hitting it once per participant.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri i updated with the code to save

Comment: @bdash but i need to check first if the object has exists in my bd, if no i will save the complete object but if yes i need to update only some informations.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that requires that you use multiple write transactions instead of one? Anyway, please provide the information I mentioned in my earlier comment: a backtrace that shows what the main thread is blocked on, and information about what's taking the CPU time.

Comment: you shouldn't do writes on the UI thread and you shouldn't use N transactions instead of 1 transaction